# Locking on Action Does Not Work

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have come across some code that locks on an `Action` and have found that it does not work. Here is a (simplified and silly) version of the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var settings = new Settings(0);
        Action<int> threadAction = i =>
        {
            BusyBody.DoSomething(settings.GetANumber, settings.SetANumber, i);
        };
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { threadAction(1); });
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { threadAction(2); });
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    class Settings
    {
        int i;

        public Settings(int i)
        {
            this.i = i;
        }

        public int GetANumber() => i;

        public void SetANumber(int i) => this.i = i;
    }

    class BusyBody
    {
        public static void DoSomething(Func<int> getInt, Action<int> setInt, int i)
        {
            lock (setInt)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Getting int: " + getInt());
                Console.WriteLine("i " + i);
                setInt(i);
                Console.WriteLine("set");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect this to produce the following output:

```
Getting int: 0
i 1
set
Getting int: 1
i 2
set
```

OR

```
Getting int: 0
i 2
set
Getting int: 2
i 1
set
```

Depending on whichever thread gets through the `lock` first. However this isn't what I am seeing. Instead I see:

```
Getting int: 0
i 2
Getting int: 0
i 1
set
set
```

It looks like both threads enter the `lock`. Why does this happen? The `Action` being locked is the same method from the same object so shouldn't the references be the same?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think what's going on is that you're creating and locking on two different `delegate` objects that reference the same method.  But I don't know how to state it more formally than that.  Skeet?

Comment: "However this isn't what I am seeing". Can you show us what you are seeing?

Comment: @YacoubMassad question updated with the output I am seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're locking on two different objects.

This line:

```
BusyBody.DoSomething(settings.GetANumber, settings.SetANumber, i);
```

is short for this:

```
BusyBody.DoSomething(new Func<int>(settings.GetANumber), new Action<int>(settings.SetANumber), i);
```

The two `new Func<int>(...)` and `new Action<int>(...)` expressions will produce new delegate objects on each call, thus you're not locking on the same object instance.

If you want to share these objects they have to be created once:

```
...
Func<int> getANumber = settings.GetANumber;
Action<int> setANumber = settings.SetANumber;
Action<int> threadAction = i =>
{
    BusyBody.DoSomething(getANumber, setANumber, i);
};
...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you cast a method to an `Action` multiple times (when you pass `settings.SetANumber`), that does not mean that you get the same `Action` object. You get *multiple* `Action` objects that do the same thing.

Try this:

```
 Action<int> set_action = settings.SetANumber;

 Action<int> threadAction = i =>
 {
     BusyBody.DoSomething(settings.GetANumber, set_action, i);
 };
```

This makes sure that you have a single `Action` object.